# What does やけに上から来る means about a person?

Tags: grammar, meaning, expressions, reading-comprehension

**I met this expression when reading, MC called to an "大沢退魔師紹介所/ Exorcist Referral Agency" (Ghost Buster ?) since he needs to solve a series of paranormal incidents at his school. There are 2 girls who're answering his call. Hope someone can answers my question.**

清楚な女の子の声「…おほん。その大沢某とやらは存じ上げませんが、超優秀な退魔師でしたら、すぐにでもご紹介できますよ」

MC「えっ、本当ですか？」

元気な女の子の声「アンタ運がいいわね。いまなら特別に、さいっきょーの退魔師をハケンしてあげるんだからっ」

**なんか、この元気なほうの子はやけに上から来るな。**

Comment: Which part of it is causing you difficulty, やけに or 上から来る or anything else?

Comment: 2nd part , but i got an answer already thank you

Comment: What is the answer if you do not mind ?

Comment: it means something likes "For some reason, she speaks quite bossy/arrogant eh ?"

Comment: The 元気な女 is pretty bossy indeed.